# Issues with setting variable in $rootScope in one controller for another

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have moved all of my code for my web app out to http://dev.sortsof.com.

The issue I am having is that once you search for something, it stores your search in the left hand menu using my `$localstorage` service. If you click on an item from the menu, it won't populate the results in my main area.

However, if you search for something in the main area, and then choose and item from the menu, it will search for the results.

Any ideas on what may be causing the items in the menu area to not load in the `$rootScope.items` array?

Comment: I get an error in the console when choosing an item from the left menu `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined in Services.js:87`

Comment: @Ronnie - please try it again. Fixed a syntax error.

Comment: Still getting the error but line 88 now

Comment: @Ronnie - let me take another look. Can you also try to clear your browser cache?

Comment: I did, it is happening even when I do my initial search. I type my input, hit search...loading..results show and then bam, error. Looks liek you need to add another if for the key `galleryPlusPictureURL`

Comment: @Ronnie - Okay, I think I got it all cleared up. :fingerscrossed:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151756/discussion-between-ronnie-and-user1278584).